# Codeigniter How do I populate rest of form based on dropdown?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, html-select, populate

This is my first time posting on SO, also I am relatively new to Codeigniter and PHP. My question is this, I need to populate the rest of the form based on value selected from dropdown. If someone chooses for example 2 then it should populate 2 fields and so on

```
$dvalue = array(
          'select'                      => 'Select Value',
          '1'                           => '1',
          '2'                           => '2',
          '3'                           => '3',  
          '4'                           => '4'    
           );

$js = 'onChange=""';              
echo form_dropdown('Amount of Directors', $dvalue, 'select', $js);
```

So I have no idea what the JS should look like (if any)? My apologies, I did read through the CI manual (Form Helper). Everything else works.

Any help would be much appreciated (even if you can only point me in the right direction).

Thanks in advance
Steville

Comment: I omitted to mention, but is was thinking even if it unhides lets say a div tag which wraps the other form fields? dunno what is best

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found a solution and it appears to be working well. I implemented the following script

```
<_script>
  $('#Dir1').hide();
  $("#dvalue").on('change', function() {
   $('#Dir1').hide();
     if($('#dvalue').val() == '0') { 
 $('#Dir1').hide(); 
 } 
 else {
 $('#Dir1').show();
 }
     });
 <_/script>
```

Many thank you's community! :)